# Unable to create "ShareLibrary" with datacontract using SVCUTIL

Tags: xsd, datacontractserializer, datacontract, xmlserializer, svcutil.exe

**Case:
I have a set of xsd files that define common types used in WSDL definitions (Header, ApplicationError). Each webservice inports, next to the service specific types, one or more of these shared types.**

When generating a proxy for services I keep getting copies of these shared types per service proxy, so I desides to put these in a shares library and use /reference to include these types. I could not get this to work.

First of all, generating a proxy and including all *.xsd workes fine, and contract are generated. Then using the svcutil per xsd, with the /dconly parameter, does not work. Both /XmlSerializer as /DataContractSerializer. Only /importXmlType (or xsd.exe) work.

Then if I put them in a class project, add the generated code, compile and use this on for the /reference parameter, I still get code generated for these types.

Even if I use the classes, generated for the proxy, they are still not recognized by svcutil.

Anyone have experience with this pattern, and perhaps has encounters these same issues?

> Error messages for both XmlSerializer as DataContractSerializer
>   svcutil /dconly /ser:XmlSerializer  ApplicatieFout-v0200-b03.xsd
>
> Error: Type 'ApplicatieFout' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.customer.nl/ApplicatieFout-v0200' cannot be imported.
>   Form on element 'FoutCode' must be qualified. E ither change the
>   schema so that the types can map to data contract types or use
>   ImportXmlType or use a different serializer.
>
> If you are using the /dataContractOnly option to import data contract
>   types and are getting this error message, consider using xsd.exe
>   instead. Types generated by xsd.exe may be used in the Windows
>   Communication Foundation after applying the
>   XmlSerializerFormatAttribute attribute on your service contract.
>   Alternatively , consider using the /importXmlTypes option to import
>   these types as XML types to use with DataContractFormatAttribute
>   attribute on your service contract.

Answer (score 1):

In our support activities, we see requests like yours quite often, sufficient to call out a pattern. Without seeing the actual XSDs and WSDLs, it is hard (for anyone) to say if you ran into a product bug or something else.

However, what I learned over the years is that in general tools that deal with XSD to code binding are always limited; to work around those limitations, the solution is to start with a careful planning of the XSD content and how WSDLs must use that content. It is easier if I control the process of generating WSDL and XSD; when I "inherit" or "adopt" other's, I apply my own refactoring.

On .NET, my solution to your case is a to use a little trick based on WSDL's specification support for componentized authoring. Let's assume you have WSDLs for two services, `Abc` and `Xyz`. I build a "wrapper" WSDL like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    targetNamespace="http://services.paschidev.com/wrapper/usecase_a/1/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://services.paschidev.com/service_abc/1/" location="AbcService.wsdl" />
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://services.paschidev.com/service_xyz/1/" location="XyzService.wsdl" />
  <wsdl:types />
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Feed this through your utility (successfully tested this with Visual Studio 2010, ***Add Service Reference*** command), and you're done.

The fine print... For all this to work with a high success rate, all the WSDLs you wish to combine **must** follow this rule: common XSD must come from common sources.

If service `Abc` needs `{urn:paschidev-com:xsd:common:1}something` and `Xyz` needs the same, then a `{urn:paschidev-com:xsd:common:1}something` must come from the same source URI for both WSDLs.

The test is rather simple for me: I use [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com)'s (I am associated with it) ***Extract XSDs*** command by pointing it at the **wrapper** WSDL. When prompted, I let it create an XSR project; if the collection created from the generated XSDs compiles fine, it means that there are no duplicate XSD definitions. If the compilation gives "already defined" errors, a report tells me which XSD component is duplicated, i.e. comes from two or more different source Uris. I refactor each component to keep one source uri; then try again.

Sometimes, even if I get the XSDs right, svcutil or xsd might still choke; if that happens, it is then something unrelated to the wrapper; it would manifest itself even without this wrapper. Which means it is always a good idea to ensure that before any refactoring happens, each individual WSDL works well on its own.

Comment: The problem i'm currently running into is that svcutil is unable to generate data contracts from the individual xsd's but is able to generate a proxy class from the wall that actually referenced these same xsd's. Any idea on that?

Comment: Is there any way you could share what the error is, and the command line?

Comment: This is already in the final part of the post. I put an example command line with ApplicatieFout.xsd. Is that sufficient?